# Creating a dll for mIRC using Delphi 2010

Tags: dll, delphi-2010, mirc

Using Delphi 2010, I am trying to write a dll for mIRC. Here is some information from the mIRC help file

> Technical notes
>
> This section contains technical information for programmers who want to create DLLs for use with mIRC.
>
> The routine in the DLL being called must be of the form:
>
> int __stdcall procname(HWND mWnd, HWND aWnd, char *data, char *parms, BOOL show, BOOL nopause)
>
> mWnd is the handle to the main mIRC window.
>
> aWnd is the handle of the window in which the command is being issued, this might not be the currently active window if the command is being called by a remote script.
>
> data is the information that you wish to send to the DLL. On return, the DLL can fill this variable with the command it wants mIRC to perform if any.
>
> The DLL can return an integer to indicate what it wants mIRC to do:
>
> 0 means that mIRC should /halt processing
>
> 1 means that mIRC should continue processing
>
> 2 means that it has filled the data variable with a command which it wants mIRC to perform, and has filled parms with the parameters to use, if any, when performing the command.
>
> 3 means that the DLL has filled the data variable with the result that $dll() as an identifier should return.

The following code, which is supposed to reverse input text, compiles OK, but the results of using the dll are not what I expected.

```
function Reverse(mWnd, aWnd: hWnd; Data, Parms: PChar; Show, NoPause: Boolean): Integer; stdcall;
var
  Temp: String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Temp, Length(Data));
  for I := 0 to Length(Data) do
  begin
    Temp[I] := Data[Length(Data)- I]; // Reversing string by retrieving characters from Data one at a time
  end;
  StrCopy(Data, PChar(Temp)); // Putting reversed string back into data
  Result := 3;
end;
exports
    Reverse;
begin
end.
```

For example calling the dll from mIRC as `//say $dll(mydll,Reverse,hello)` gives an output of just 'o'. If the parameter is 'hello sailor' the output is 'orilsao llhe'.  I have tried unsuccessfully to trace the operation of the code, but I cannot make sense of how the Data value changes. I suspect it my own limited knowledge of PChar behaviour is a contributing factor. I welcome any advice that may help.  Cheers

Comment: Boolean is wrong. Use LongBool. Or BOOL. The strings need to be PAnsiChar rather than PWideChar. This has been discussed so many times here.

Comment: It may have been discussed so many times before, but one's searches missed it all. At the time of my post, I had not searched here for PChar behaviour in Delphi versions post Delphi7, and why would I? Initially I thought that I must be doing something wrong. I don't have your knowledge which is why I pasted the code.  I thought the problem was me. The little that I did recall about memory and pointers focussed me on how the debugging watches behave so differently in Delphi 7 vs Delphi 2010. Cheers.

Comment: You should read the documentation. The Unicode change was huge and very heavily documented. Don't skimp on keeping up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I changed PChar to PAnsiChar in to function definition.
`function Reverse(mWnd, aWnd: hWnd; Data, Parms: PAnsiChar; Show, NoPause: Boolean): Integer; stdcall;`

I changed PChar to PAnsiChar in the line `StrCopy(Data, PChar(Temp)); // Putting reversed string back into data` and now my problem is no more.
Just a tad more googling enable me to make the changes. Actually writing down my problem in this forum helped me zero in a solution.

Cheers, and thanks.

Comment: You still need to change `Boolean` to `BOOL`, like David told you. `Boolean` is 1 byte, `BOOL` is 4 bytes. When translating between languages. always use the same data type names whenever possible. Delphi has a definition for `BOOL` for compatibility with other APIs that also use `BOOL`, as it is a [standard Win32 data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx).